# Headband not following rest of head

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

Sorry for the poor title as well as any issues with terminology as I am new to blender. Basically I have a character with a headband (which is separate from the rest of the body mesh but same object) and a head bone:

[image: weights with head bone selected]

However when I rotate the bone, the headband is displaced on the character's head:

[image: head bone rotated, showing issue]

I have tried selecting the headband part of the mesh with <kbd>L</kbd> in edit mode, then using the vertex groups window to `assign` this to the head bone. Any help would be awesome!

Here is the file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "However when I rotate the bone, the headband is displaced on the character's head"?

Comment: Upload your file.

Comment: @Leander my apologies, I have uploaded it.

Comment: @Tak I've uploaded a gif that hopefully illustrates. I've also added the blend file itself.

Comment: @AndyPerlitch There must be a vertex group on the headband which still influences it. Can you test if a) there is only one vertex group with the name of your head bone on the headband mesh, and b) if not, what the weights in the other groups are. If weights are very small, they still have an influence, but in the viewport they'd be drawn in red still

Comment: @AndyPerlitch Thanks for uploading the file, it was helpful to find out the cause of your problem, answer provided with screenshots and an updated blend file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that although the head and head bands are assigned to the same vertexgroup they are not connected together, which results in giving them different "visual" effect when rotating the parent bone even though they have the same weight.

To fix this you will connect them. To do so, go to the Head Vertex Group, then select it. Then switch to Vertex Selection instead of Face selection. Then go to Mesh menu -> Vertices -> Connect Vertices. And voila it's done.

Steps:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Updated Blend file:

[image]

Comment: @AndyPerlitch you are welcome! Well, I'll let you know when I visit the US and be near Silicone Valley to meet and play with the Frisbee and your dog :)

Comment: drop me a line, I'll show you around! :-D

Comment: @AndyPerlitch Awesome! I will :)